# Generate a library and return responses

Tags: c#

I have generated a class library, I want to return two responses.

Now I get an error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property

My questions:

1. How to fix the error?
2. How to return two responses? I have to reference it in another console application.

Code:

```
namespace MessagingConfiguration
{
    public class InmateDetail
    {
        public GetConfig(string Pin, int Id)
        { 
            AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient client = new AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient("http://www.test.my.com/MessageService/api/");
           InmateDetailResponse inmateDetail = client.Get(new InmateDetailRequest() { InmatePIN = Pin, FacilityId = Id });
           InmateInboxResponse inmateInbox = client.Get(new InmateInboxRequest() { InmatePkey = inmateDetail.Inmate.pkey.ToString() });
        }

     }

  }
```

Comment: Which line exactly is the error on?

Comment: I don't see any field initializers in that code. Please point out exactly what line the problem occurs on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a new model that will wrap the two existing models as properties:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public InmateDetailResponse InmateDetail { get; set; }
    public InmateInboxResponse InmateInbox { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your method return this new model:

```
namespace MessagingConfiguration
{
    public class InmateDetail
    {
        public MyModel GetConfig(string Pin, int Id)
        { 
            AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient client = new AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient("http://www.test.my.com/MessageService/api/");
            InmateDetailResponse inmateDetail = client.Get(new InmateDetailRequest() { InmatePIN = Pin, FacilityId = Id });
            InmateInboxResponse inmateInbox = client.Get(new InmateInboxRequest() { InmatePkey = inmateDetail.Inmate.pkey.ToString() });

            MyModel model = new MyModel();
            model.InmateDetail = inmateDetail;
            model.InmateInbox = inmateInbox;

            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you call the method you will have access to the two properties:

```
MyModel model = new InmateDetail().GetConfig("some pin", 123);
// here you can use model.InmateDetail and model.InmateInbox
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the incriminating line is this:

`InmateDetailResponse inmateDetail = client.Get(new InmateDetailRequest() { InmatePIN = Pin, FacilityId = Id });`

I would suggest you follow the standard .NET convention of naming your variables/parameters with a lower-case letter to start:

`public GetConfig(string pin, int id)`

This will make the incriminating line change to:

`InmateDetailResponse inmateDetail = client.Get(new InmateDetailRequest() { InmatePIN = pin, FacilityId = id });`

Without the code for `InmateDetailRequest`, I can only hope that it has the publically settable fields `InmatePIN` (should really be called `InmatePin`) and `FacilityId`.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the fields in a constructor.

```
namespace MessagingConfiguration
{
    public class InmateDetail
    {
        public InmateDetail(string Pin, int Id)
        { 
            AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient client = new AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient("http://www.test.my.com/MessageService/api/");
           InmateDetailResponse inmateDetail = client.Get(new InmateDetailRequest() { InmatePIN = Pin, FacilityId = Id });
           InmateInboxResponse inmateInbox = client.Get(new InmateInboxRequest() { InmatePkey = inmateDetail.Inmate.pkey.ToString() });
        }    
     }    
  }
```